# Why can't access df data in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a table where column names are not really organized like they have different years of data with different column numbers.

So I should access each data through specified column names. 
I am using this syntax to access a column.

```
df = df[["2018/12"]]
```

But when I just want to extract numbers under that column, using

```
df.iloc[0,0]
```

it throws an error like

```
single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

So I am using

```
df.loc[0]
```

but it has the column name with the numeric data.

How can I extract just the number of each row?

Below is the CSV data

```
    Closing Date,2014/12,2015/12,2016/12,2017/12,2018/12,Trend
Net Sales,"31,634","49,924","62,051","68,137","72,590",
""
Net increase,"-17,909","-16,962","-34,714","-26,220","-29,721",
Net Received,-,-,-,-,-,
Net Paid,-328,"-6,038","-9,499","-9,375","-10,661",
```

Comment: When you make `df` equal to a one dimensional Series, trying to index on a second dimension will fail (try `iloc[0]`). You can turn that into a list if you want with `.tolist()` or you could get just the value or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following data frame `df` imported from your csv:

```
   Closing Date  2014/12  2015/12  2016/12  2017/12  2018/12
0     Net Sales   31,634   49,924   62,051   68,137   72,590
1  Net increase  -17,909  -16,962  -34,714  -26,220  -29,721
2  Net Received        -        -        -        -        -
3      Net Paid     -328   -6,038   -9,499   -9,375  -10,661
```

then by doing `df = df[["2018/12"]]` you create a new **data frame** with one column and `df.iloc[0,0]` will work perfectly well here returning `72,590`. I you wrote `df = df["2018/12"]` you'd create a new **series** and here `df.iloc[0,0]` will throw an error 'too many indexers', because it's a one-dimensional series.

Anyway, if you need the values of a series, use the `values` attribute (or `to_numpy()` for version 0.24 or later) to get the data as array or `to_list()` to get them as a list.

But I guess what you really want is to have your table transposed:

```
df = df.set_index('Closing Date').T
```

to the following more logical form:

```
Closing Date Net Sales Net increase Net Received Net Paid
2014/12         31,634      -17,909            -     -328
2015/12         49,924      -16,962            -   -6,038
2016/12         62,051      -34,714            -   -9,499
2017/12         68,137      -26,220            -   -9,375
2018/12         72,590      -29,721            -  -10,661
```

Here, `df.loc['2018/12','Net Sales']` gives you `72,590` etc.

Comment: @BangolPhoenix Did this answer your question and solve your issue? If so then please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If not please comment. This helps keep this site useful and enables others with similar questions quickly find an answer.